# Where is the folder for Installing tensorflow with pip, Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

just installed tensorflow using pip with the command:

`$ pip install tensorflow`

On the ["Getting Started" for Tensorflow](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md) they have an example for convolutional neural networks

`$ python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py`

Where is that directory located when installing with pip?

Comment: If you don't find it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, check `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Installing with pip, installs the packages to the directory "site-packages".

The following code shows the location of tensorflow as well as where pip installs the packages:

```
$ pip show tensorflow
```

Which return:

```
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.com/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: six, numpy
```

here `Location:` shows where the package is installed with

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow
```

---

EDIT:

As some people pointed out in the newer versions of tensorflow and depending on the `$ echo $TENSORFLOW` you need to look in either

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python{2,3}.X/{site,dist}-packages/tensorflow
```

Or

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework
```

Comment: .@eleijonmarck - Is it possible to have two different `TensorFlow` install on same system with `pip`? I want to build one with MKL support and one without MKL.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil i would use virtualenv. `pip install virtualenv`. `virtualenv env -p python3`

Comment: Thank you! Best answer, ever)

Comment: Tack you! @Oleksandr

Comment: If you install tensorflow with anaconda, it is in /anaconda3/envs/tensorflow-sessions/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where is the `$TENSORFLOW` environment variable is set. Let's help it setup.

First check, `$ echo $TENSORFLOW` if it returns blank, you need to setup the access of tensorflow in any directory from your console.

There are two cases of that:

1. In case you have python from anaconda library/environment (let say you have anaconda2), the usually installed location is: `~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-package/tensorflow`
2. In case of Python2.x or Python3.x, x = is subversion like 2.7 or 3.5, the usually installed location is: `/usr/local/lib/python2.x/site-packages/tensorflow`

Now that you have identified the python version, use it as the onetime path in bash or profile. Type this Linux code:

`$ vi ~/.bashrc`

add this line at the bottom of the bashrc file.

`$ export $TENSORFLOW="~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow:$PATH"`

check again in a new terminal

`$ echo $TENSORFLOW` to verify.

or use `source ~/.bashrc' to reload the new environment variables.

Now you can all set to use

`$ python tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py`

directly by

`$ python -m tensorflow.models.image.mnist.convolutional.py`

Now your program as per description in TensorFlow tutorial will search these path with period (.) instead of "/" with the `-m` argument.

Comment: FYI

In my case TensorFlow 1.4.1 is installed in
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework

NOT site-packages.

Comment: @willSapgreen easier with 'pip show tensorflow' to get the location.