# speed benchmark for testing tensorflow install

Tags: tensorflow

I'm doubting whether tensorflow is correctly configured on my gpu box, since it's about 100x slower per iteration to train a simple linear regression model (batchsize = 32, 1500 input features, 150 output variables) on my fancy gpu machine than on my laptop.

I'm using a Titan X, with a modern cpu, etc. nvidia-smi says that I'm only at 10% gpu utilization, but I expect that's because of the small batchsizes. I'm not using a feed_dict to move data into the computation graph. Everything is coming via a tf.decode_csv and tf.train.shuffle_batch.

Does anyone have any recommendations for how to easily test whether my install is correct?  Are there any simple speed benchmarks? The speed difference between my laptop and the gpu machine is so dramatic that I'm expecting that things aren't configured properly.

Comment: Some examples are not optimized for GPU and can get 100x slower when GPU is enabled because of copies, here's one https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/838

Answer (score 19):

Try `tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py`, that'll print per-step timing.

On Tesla K40c that should get about `16 ms` per step, while about `120 ms` for CPU-only on my 3 year old machine

---

*Edit:* This moved to the `models` repositories: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py.

The `convolutional.py` file is now at `models/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py`

Comment: Just for the record. I'm using a GeForce GTX 960M and get step times from 16.1 to 17.7, but mostly about 16.2.

Comment: If you're searching the install location of tensorflow (where the file is located), look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616732/where-is-the-folder-for-installing-tensorflow-with-pip-mac-osx

Comment: looks like convolutional.py got removed, you can still see it in github history -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6431560b7ec3565154cb9cdc9c827db78ccfebe7/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L265

Comment: It moved to the `models` repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py

Comment: titan xp gets about 3.8ms

Comment: core 2 quad 6600 (CPU) - around 500ms

Comment: 1050 ti  - around 10ms with tf 1.12 cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.3.1 [most probably]

Comment: ~3.5ms average step time on MSI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 GAMING X 8GB GDDR5X

Comment: Took 6.5 ms (amortized) on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5.

Comment: This doesn't work on TF 2.0 even using the upgrade utilities

Comment: Saidly it seems to not work anymore is there a new way ?

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 19):

Extending Yaroslavs answer: 
Here is how to do the entire testing process (CUDA and cudNN installed already)

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

Create a Virtual Environment for tensorflow and install tensorflow

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 tf-venv3
source tf-venv3/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Run the model within your Virtual Environment

```
python models/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py
```

My GTX 1070 needs ~5ms per step

**Note:** On Geforce 1050 Ti it takes ~10ms per step
[image]

Comment: I ran "watch nvidia-smi" in another terminal and saw the temperature of my GPU increase while convolutional ran.

Comment: GTX 1050 Ti 9.0 - 12ms per step

Comment: getting 8.1 to 8.3 ms in 1050 Ti on CUDA 9.2 cuDNN 7.1 with Tensorflow build made using Compute 6 and AVX2 enabled

Comment: Is it ~10ms for one step, or for 100? Seems like 10ms per 100 steps would be crazy fast, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Rtx 2070 @ 1890Mhz - 4.0 ms per step, what a frustration... No better than Gtx 1070. Can someone test on Rtx 2080Ti?

Comment: ~ 3.6ms on my 1080TI

Comment: 5.5 ms on CUDA 10.0 and GTX 1060.

Comment: ~2.8ms with RTX 2070 running CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.0

Comment: ~2.4ms with RTX 2080 Ti running Cuda 10.0 on Windows

Comment: ~2.7ms on a DGX-1 (8x V100 GPUs with 32GB RAM each)

Comment: ~3.7 ms with RTX 2080, Cuda 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.5 on Ubuntu 19.10 (and TF 2.0 compatibility switched on)

Comment: ~2.6ms with 1080Ti, CUDA 10.0, cuDNN 7.6.5, and TF 1.15, on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: All files under `tutorials` are deleted: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/d160e2fda19e5911f1d2801073f84e92b8279e0f

Answer (score 2):

The answer [given by Yaroslav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710218/7708542) and [extended by Patrice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327563/7708542) may be simply extended once again to work with TensorFlow v2.

Just in line 35 of `convolutional.py`, instead of:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

type in:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

The file `convolutional.py` was removed from the tensorflow repo but it can still be found [in the repo history](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/86ecc9730d751c1f72e3bfecac958166390f4125/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py).