# How can I determine the speed of my Tensorflow on my GPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I just started with **Tensorflow (Version 2.3.0)** and installed it on my GPU (in an virtual environment using python 3.5). That seems to work fine. I am using a **nvidia geforce 1060** with windows 10.
Now my Question is: How can find the speed of my tensorflow working. I found this test: [speed benchmark for testing tensorflow install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703201/speed-benchmark-for-testing-tensorflow-install) but it seems to me old to work with my versions. Is there something like it for tensorflow 2? And how can I start it ?
I would like to compare it to another computer to find out which one is how much faster.

Cheers

PS: If I can improve my post just let me now.

Comment: Yes I have answerde the question already but can mark  it in two days as solved

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any official tensorflow benchmarks, but in the [TensorFlow models repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official) there are some official models that work with TensorFlow 2 which you could use to train (e.g. MNIST) and compare the training speed on two machines.

Or you could follow one of the [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) to implement and test the speed of a small network.

Comment: yea sure that would work but I was more like looking for a benchmark test not only one training of a model on two machines

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the full answer in another post which I didn't found earlier:

[What is the proper way to benchmark part of tensorflow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178521/what-is-the-proper-way-to-benchmark-part-of-tensorflow-graph/63591009#63591009)